# Highcharts Spider Web Label overlap (Top and Bottom)

Tags: highcharts

I created an Spider Web chart using highcharts, but I'm getting overlapping labels in the top most and lower most labels. I tried wrapping them and also tried staggering the labels, but I wasn't able to prevent them from overlapping.

```
$(function () {
$('#spiderchartFull').highcharts({
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line',
        marginLeft: 120,
        marginRight: 120
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Liste des interdépendances a la biodiversité et aux services écologiques'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Détaillé'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Production végétale',
            'Production animale',
            'Produits biotiques marins',
            'Produits biotiques d\'eau douce',
            'Aquaculture',
            'Eau potable',
            'Matières minérales',
            'Energie renouvelable issue du vivant',
            'Energie non renouvelable issue du  vivant',
            'Energie renouvelable abiotique',
            'Dépollution',
            'Assimilation des déchets',
            'Régulation des flux gazeux',
            'Régulation des flux hydriques',
            'Régulation des phénomènes érosifs',
            'Régulation de la qualité de l\'air',
            'Régulation de la qualité de l\'eau',
            'Régulation de la qualité des sols',
            'Régulation du climat global',
            'Régulation du climat local',
            'Maintenance du cycle de vie et  protection des habitats',
            'Régulation des pathogènes et parasites',
            'Conservation des stocks génétiques',
            'Recherche scientifique',
            'Education',
            'Esthétiques et culturels',
            'Religieux',
            'Récréation',
            'Volontariat'],
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                width: 150,

            }
        },
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Dépendances aux SE',
        data: [1.0, 2.0, 3.6, 4.7, 5.0, 1.1, 2.75, 4.33, 4.43, 3.52, 1.0, 2.0, 3.6, 4.7, 5.0, 1.1, 2.75, 4.33, 4.43, 3.52, 1.0, 2.0, 3.6, 4.7, 5.0, 1.1, 2.75, 4.33, 4.43],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Transactions monétaires associées',
        data: [2.0, 3.0, 2.6, 1.7, 1.0, 1.3, 2.235, 4.323, 4.43, 4.52, 2.0, 1.0, 3.6, 3.7, 5.0, 1.1, 2.75, 4.33, 4.43, 3.52, 1.0, 2.0, 3.6, 4.7, 5.0, 1.1, 2.75, 4.33, 4.43],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }],

    legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            width: 100
        },
    }
});
```

});

Here you can see the highchart I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfaav/4/

Comment: I advice to change size of chart, because you have too many datalabels and physically is not possible to position it that small div.

Comment: The size of the DIV is not the issue (changing it will result in the same problem). The problem is the spacing between the labels and the graph. If there was a way to add a margin or padding to have the labels further away than that would solve the overlapping issue.

Comment: hey,I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how useful is that kind of graph, but you can set `tickInterval`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfaav/5/

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same problem.I solved it using 'useHTML' and some javascript of my own.
Below is the code.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0,

    labels: {
        useHTML: false,
        style: {
            width: '240px'
        }
                ,
        formatter: function () {
            if ('Is an ideal holiday destination' === this.value) {
                 return '<span id="spn_itisideal"><span style="">' + this.value + '</span>';

            }
            else if ('Is a modern and trendy place' === this.value) {
                return '<span id="spn_isamodern"><span style="">' + this.value + '</tspan>';
            }
            else if ('Is a popular destination' === this.value)
            { return '<span id="spn_isapopular"><span style="">' + this.value + '</span>'; }
            else if ('Has great infrastructure' === this.value)
            { return '<span id="spn_hasgreatinfrastructure"><span style="">' + this.value + '</span>'; }
            else {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

when you set useHTML to true,the x-axis labels are rendered as html.I pick those labels that are overlapping in the formatter function and wrap them up with an span with respective id.
after my chart is loaded i use a javascript function to call these spans and adjust them according to my will.

```
function alterWebChart() {//Adjust x-axis label span.
    $('#spn_itisideal').parent().css('left', '268.273px');
    $('#spn_isamodern').parent().css('left', '479.727px');
    $('#spn_isapopular').parent().css('left', '260.526px');
    $('#spn_hasgreatinfrastructure').parent().css('left', '510.974px');
}
```

Comment: bt with this method i'm having problem in printing.Let me know if somebody has found any other method.